# Variable doesn't get defined/updated after function processes?

Tags: php

I have coded some alerting system.

But let's not look at the system itself, Let's look at how will the system know that the system really did sent the alert/error to the browsing user.

I have made something so when you randomly go to ?alert=name, without doing any error, it will say 'No errors'.
But if the system makes you go to ?alert=name, it will echo the error.

How I handle posts

```
function postComment() {
    if (!empty($_POST['name']) || !empty($_POST['comment'])) {
        $comment = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['comment']));
        $guest = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['name']));
    }
    $guestId = 1;
    if (empty($guest)) {
        $alert = 1;
        return header('location: index.php?alert=name');
    }
    if (empty($comment)) {
        $alert = 2;
        return header('location: index.php?alert=comment');
    }
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['alreadyPosted'])) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `comments` (`comment_guest`, `guest_id`, `comment`, `comment_date`, `comment_time`) VALUES ('$guest', '$guestId', '$comment', CURDATE(), CURTIME())") or die(mysql_error());
        header('Location: index.php?action=sucess');
        setcookie(alreadyPosted, $cookieId+1, time() + 60);
        } else {
            $alert = 3;
            header('location: index.php?alert=delay');
        }
}
```

As you see, to check if user really getting that error, I will set $alert to whatever error number it is.

And to check if hes getting the error I will use this:

```
if (isset($_GET['alert']) == 'name') {
    if ($alert == 1) {
        echo 'hai';
    } else {
        echo 'No errors';
    }
}
```

You will probably wonder why I am doing it this way.., well because I use 1 function for post, and my  post function goes under the form, and i want the alerts to display up to the form.

Problem:

The variable either doesn't get set to the number that it is supposed to when running the function,
or.. something is blocking it from it.. I don't know..

My guess: Because the check for errors is located up to the postComment function before the variables even get set?

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['alert']) == 'name') {
        if ($alert == 1) {
            echo 'hai';
        } else {
            echo 'No errors';
        }
    }
    ?>

<form action="index.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name here" class="field">
<textarea class="textarea" name="comment" placeholder="Your comment here..."></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="send" class="blue_button" value="Post Comment">
</form><a href="#"><input type="submit" name="" id="margin" class="blue_button" value="See all messages"></a>
<br />
<?php
//Show the comments
    showComments();

    if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
        postComment();
    }

    if (isset($_GET['delete']) == "comment"){
        deleteComment();
    }

    echo '<br />';

?>
```

If it is, what is the solution?
Thanks!

Please don't start with the story about mysql_ function, I understood & I will use PDO instead, but I am using mysql_ at the moment for testing purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're redirecting on an error, and so the `$alert` variable does not get carried over.

To fix the problem add the alert type to the `$_GET` parameters:

```
function postComment()
{

  // ...

  if (empty($guest))
  {
    header('location: index.php?alert=name&alert_type=1');
    exit;
  }

  // ...

}
```

And then when you check for the error:

```
if (isset($_GET['alert']) && 'name' == $_GET['alert'])
{

  if (isset($_GET['alert_type']) && '1' == $_GET['alert_type'])
  {
    echo 'hai';
  }

  else
  {
    echo 'No errors';
  }

}
```

Note also that I fixed the error here:

```
isset($_GET['alert']) == 'name'
```

That doesn't do what I think you think it does. What you want is:

```
isset($_GET['alert']) && 'name' == $_GET['alert']
```

(Excuse the order of the comparison; I prefer to have variables on the right for comparisons as it will cause a parse error if you miss a `=` -- much better than having it run but not do what you expect)

Comment: But then I assume users can just go to index.php?alert=name&alert_type=1 and see the exact same error, right?

Comment: Yes. If you're worried about that then store the alert type in the `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Yes right, I basically forget about the $_SESSION, will try it cheers!

Answer (score -1):

if you are a newbie, you better consider using client side scripting (viz javascript) for validation as using server side validation will simple make the process longer. but as you are facing problems, this might give you the solution.

as you are redirecting the page to `index.php?alert=name'`, so $alert is never set initially when the page loads itself. when you call the function `postcomment()`, $alert is initiated but immediately destroyed when the system redirects. And as `$alert` never holds a value when you randomly visit the page, it shows `no error.`

Comment: Using javascript validation will not assure your data will come correctly. Anyone using Chrome's Developer Tools, Firebug or with javascript disabled would be able to bypass your entire client-side validation.

Comment: @PedroCordeiro but for the client side UI will be smooth and there should be both client side nd server side validation for these, in case jS is disabled, server side validation will come handy. As a user none would like to wait for the page to load completely and then to pop out some error. this is non user friendly, thus I asked him to use JS

Comment: Absolutely agree that client side validation is better for the user, strongly disagree on trusting the client to do all the validation, as you suggested. Using server side validation will not "simply make the process longer".

Comment: the process never gets longer but a average user would never like to wait to pop up errors after the page refreshed or reloaded. lets talk about sf, would you like to wait for popping the errors u do after a page refresh instead of client side validation